# Output not appearing in Visual Studio code after compile and run

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Why output is not appearing.I am new to Visual Studio and I don't know why this is happening.
I am providing a screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE1SQ.png)

and this is the code which i am getting instead of my output.

```
[Running] cd "/home/dell/src/" && g++ hello.cpp -o hello && "/home/dell/src/"hello
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.073 seconds
```

Comment: Strange, I have no idea. Something wrong with the way you've setup VS Code I guess.

Comment: This person has the same [issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1495184/i-cant-run-c-code-in-vscode). The suggestion is that you aren't saving your work before you run the compiler.

Comment: Yes @john exactly this was the problem. Thanku for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had same problem with no reason . I tried compile and run manually using g++ .
For easier compile you can create Make-File for your code .

Answer (score -2):

Main Class should be Static
Make it

```
public static int Main()
{
     cout<<"Hello World!";
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not c++. Looks like Java to me.

Comment: It's not java either, no cout in java, it's just wrong.

Comment: @cigien what made you think its not c++?

Comment: @AkashJha I imagine the syntax, have you tried compiling your code?

Comment: It doesn't look like c++ to me. More importantly, c++ compilers don't like the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/ggcbcq).

Comment: @AkashJha can you please say why we made main class static in Visual Studio ?because previously I was using Code Blocks and there, there was no need to make main class static.

Comment: @DishaNamdev This answer is simply wrong, ignore it. It's the main **function**, not main **class**, it's spelled `main` not `Main`, it's illegal to use `public` in that way in C++. Akash is clearly getting mixed up between Java and C++ and the code above is a strange mix of both.